# Issue IAM user via OPENID authorization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-application-load-balancer

I set up an ALB, that sit's in front of an ECS backend. I use a cognito user pool to authenticate the users via OAuth (with code grant). On my backend I receive all user claims and it just works nice.

However, I think the most secure and easiest way is, when i can associate an IAM user to the cognito user, which is passed with the user claims. Is there a way to do this in combination with ALB authentication?

My architecture:

Client --> ALB --> AWS Cognito --> ECS